# How to build CDK Assembly using Python aws_cdk.cx_api

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I'm desperate so any help is appreciated.

I'm trying to modify my current CDK out using cloud assembly in Python.

I can't find any examples, nor proper documentation for python, only reference guide.

This is my code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import aws_cdk.cx_api as cxapi
import aws_cdk.cloud_assembly_schema as cxschema

class my_class():

def synth():
    ASSEMBLY_PATH = 'igor_cdk'
    result = subprocess.run(['cdk', 'synth', '-o', ASSEMBLY_PATH], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    my_stuff = result.stdout.decode('utf-8')
    
    new_stack_name = original_stack_name+TEMP_OUT
    print(new_stack_name)
    cloud_assembly = cxapi.CloudAssembly(ASSEMBLY_PATH);
    orig_stack_assembly = cloud_assembly.get_stack_by_name(original_stack_name)
    logical_Ids = orig_stack_assembly.find_metadata_by_type("aws:cdk:logicalId")
    cab = cxapi.CloudAssemblyBuilder(ASSEMBLY_PATH)
    cab.add_artifact(new_stack_name, type = cxschema.ArtifactType.ASSET_MANIFEST, properties = orig_stack_assembly.manifest)
```

Then, In my dummy test, I call this:
print(stack_info.synth("Test", "Targeta"))

And that's executed with pytest.

Just for comparison, I got it working in Typescript:

```
const cab: CloudAssemblyBuilder = new CloudAssemblyBuilder(ASSEMBLY_PATH);
cab.addArtifact(new_stack_name, stack.manifest);
cab.buildAssembly();
```

I expected similar/same behavior, but I just can't figure out how to do it in python, and since my whole code base is in python, I'd just love to have it all done in one place, rather than reworking the whole thing in TS.

Edit:
If I pass the stack.manifest, I'm getting the following error:

```
 jsii.errors.JSIIError: Value did not match any type in union: 
Wire struct type '@aws-cdk/cloud-assembly-schema.ArtifactManifest' does not match expected '@aws-cdk/cloud-assembly-schema.AwsCloudFormationStackProperties', Wire struct type '@aws-cdk/cloud-assembly-schema.ArtifactManifest' does not match expected '@aws-cdk/cloud-assembly-schema.AssetManifestProperties', 
Wire struct type '@aws-cdk/cloud-assembly-schema.ArtifactManifest' does not match expected '@aws-cdk/cloud-assembly-schema.TreeArtifactProperties', 
Wire struct type '@aws-cdk/cloud-assembly-schema.ArtifactManifest' does not match expected '@aws-cdk/cloud-assembly-schema.NestedCloudAssemblyProperties'
```

And if I pass the whole stack assembly object, I run in even weirder problem:

```
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError:
  RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
      at /private/var/folders/z6/c91mcs6j4g93t2856_p_51nr0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-35iS5M/node_modules/@aws-cdk/cx-api/lib/cloud-assembly.js:307:53
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? What are you getting that you don't expect?

Comment: Updated with the errors I'm seeing.

Comment: Thank you. Will you please also post your full JavaScript & Python code, if you can? That'll help a lot.

Comment: There, added the whole python bit, one thing that comes on my mind is that I'm missing some path, and that I am using the same manifest to read and write into, instead of creating a new one, but I don't see it. 

 I did add missing bit, that this is invoked as pytest test.